# PHP dropdown populated from database

Tags: php, html, sql

I need to pull down a column of color codes for a color picker site I'm making but it won't work:

```
<select name="select" id="dropdown">
    <option id="0">-- Select Color --</option>
    <?php
        $getColors = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM color_codes");
            while($list = mysql_fetch_array($getColors)){
    ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $list ['colorID']; ?>">
        <?php echo $list['color_code'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I added `print_r($_POST);` to check for any but nothing appears. The dropdown just doesn't populate with anything. I'm a novice at this so apologies if you're looking for something more detailed.

Comment: I've been told its the mysql. I'm using PHPMyAdmin and it's telling me it's depreciated.

Comment: Obligatory security comment: please stop using deprecated code like `mysql_query` and please look into `mysqli` or `PDO`.  It really would ruin your day if your database got hacked.

Comment: Luke, that is correct.  Also look below at Habib's answer for an example of `mysqli` (though not perfect, it's a step in the right direction) and also some of the reasons why your code wasn't working.

Comment: you have to use `mysql_fetch_array($getColors, MYSQL_ASSOC)` if you want to get  a field like `$list['color_code']` .

Comment: if you switch to mysqli, you can use something like `while ($list=$conn->fetch_assoc()) { ... }`  where `$conn` is your database connection

Comment: Hi Luke. Thanks for wanting to mark this question as solved, but we don't do that here in the title. The tick against the question is fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just did a couple of changes to your code and it worked for me, Hope it works for you.

```
 <?php

$mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$sql="select * from test";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
?>
<select name="select" id="dropdown">
    <option id="0">-- Select Color --</option>

<?php
            while($list = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
        <?php echo $list['name'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: To clarify what habib answered, when you are calling a result from a query, you can't leave a space between your `while` variable and your data field, so using your more specific data, so `$list ['colorID']` would have to `$list['colorID']`.  Blank spaces mean something in most code.